# Is there a name for this "mean"?

Tags: means

We all know these means:

$$GM = \sqrt[3]{xyz} $$
$$AM = \frac{x + y + z}{3}$$
$$QM = \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{3}} $$

Of course:

$$GM \le AM \le QM $$

What about this one:

$$XM = \sqrt{\frac{xy + yz + zx}{3}} $$

Does it have its name? Are there inequalities connecting it to other means?

I did some basic search, but was surprised not to find anything.

Comment: Three upvotes in 45 seconds. Whoa!

Comment: It can be rewritten as $\sqrt{\frac{xyz}{HM}}$ where $HM$ is the harmonic mean. Not sure how helpful that is.  This in turn can be re-written as $$GM\sqrt{\frac{GM}{HM}}.$$

Comment: See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality

Comment: What does QM stand for? I assume something with Euclidean...

Comment: @Chris QM is "quadratic mean".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quantity $XM$ lies between the arithmetic and geometric means, that is $$AM\geq XM\geq GM.$$ Notice that $$3AM^2=2XM^2+QM^2,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$ and so since $AM\leq QM$, it follows that $$3AM^2=2XM^2+QM^2\geq 2XM^2 +AM^2\Rightarrow AM\geq XM.$$ The AM-GM inequality implies that $XM\geq GM$. From $(1)$ we may write $$XM=\sqrt{\frac{3AM^2-QM^2}{2}},$$ but a nicer way to express $XM$ is given in [Thomas Andrews comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416173/is-there-a-name-for-this-mean/1416194#comment2885582_1416173): $$XM=GM\sqrt{\frac{GM}{HM}}.$$

**See Also:** [Newton's inequalities.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities) More generally quantities such as $XM$ are often referred to as Elementary Symmetric Means.